# Rails ActiveRecord fire action after after_save method is done

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

In my Rails 4 Postgres applicaiton I have a Project model and a WorkingDay model with a has_many relationship between them:

`working_day.rb`

```
class WorkingDay > ActiveRecord::Base
  # working_times: text that is parsed into yml json format

  belongs_to :project
end
```

and `project.rb`

```
class Project > ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :working_days

  # total_cost: decimal based on calculations of working_times of each working_day

  before_save :calculate_total_cost

  def calculate_total_cost
    # carry out certain calculations based on working_days of this project
    self
  end 

  def regen_working_days(wd_json_data)
    self.working_days.each(&:destroy)
    wd_json_data.each do |wd_data|
      self.working_days.create(wd_data)
    end 
    self.save!
    self
  end 
end
```

The issue I am having is that once the `regen_working_days` is fired with the correct `wd_json_data` parameters, the `total_cost` is not calculated correctly. It is actually calculated based on values of previous `working_days`, which means that in the instance this method is fired, the new working_day objects are not yet created and the old ones are still there.

Is there any way to make the `self.save!` part of the `regen_working_days` method be fired only after all other transactions are finished? Or am I generally wrong in the way I handle nested objects and the transactions associated with them with my approach?

Comment: sidenote - you do not need `self` in any place you used it.

Comment: Personally i think that even though `self` may not be needed, it massively increases readability of code (saying "this is a method not a local variable"), and so it's good practise to use it.  Coding isn't a contest for who can use the fewest characters (well, ok, those contests do exist but they generate extremely unreadable code).

Comment: In the regen_working_days it is legacy, because some time ago I used save instead of save! and here I need this method to be chained in other parts of the application.

Comment: But the real question is how to correctly use transactions here so that the `before_save` callbacks are only used once all the old `working_days` are gone and new ones are correctly created in the database, not before.

Comment: Can you add some context as to what exactly you're wanting to accomplish and why? Just layman terms that explain what you need to do. That'll be helpful to figure out if any of what you're trying to do is necessary or could be structured better.

Comment: @MaxWilliams 100% agree, that programming is not a contest of using the fewest characters possible, but for me personally `self` is arguably a mean of increasing readability.

Comment: I have a method that takes a json and updates the nested working_days of the project. That method needs to also affect the price, which is the project attribute calculated before the project is saved. The problem is that this method calculates the price based on old values of the nested working_days, and I do not understand why.

Comment: I tried even calling `self.save!` twice or many times, which would be a completely wrong solution, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: where is caller of ` regen_working_days`?

Comment: Inside the projects controller. Something like `if @project.regen_working_days render json: @project.as_json`. I am still working on this part.

Comment: @VitalyStanchits that is too weak part, what kind of array is passed to the func, and what is the purpose to use the exatly array here?

Comment: Use a mutex or transaction.

Comment: @virtuexru that is the exactly the core of the question. How can you use the Transaction logic here to begin with?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ the array here is a Json array, a sanitized version of the JSON request coming via AJAX PUT request. Looks something like `"working_days" => [{"date" => "12.02.2015", "timeframes" => "... very long hash with lots of data ..."}]`. The reason I am doing this this way is because my idea here is to take a hash I build in the frontend logic, and turn it into normal objects you can use. What is important is that I can not do price calculation via JS, it has to be done in the backend since it is too complex, and for that I need to send and receive data.

Comment: I'm aware @VitalyStanchits.. `total_cost` or whatever your data that needs to be processed first should call regen_working_days after it's finished. Instead of as an after save. Putting so much business logic in callbacks isn't scaleable.

Comment: @virtuexru OK, how do you suggest I structure my `regen_working_days` so that the `total_cost` is calculated only after the creation and deletion of `working_day` objects is finished? It may not be scalable, but here it is important that the system can handle saving up to 10 working_days at a time.

Comment: They need to be decoupled and the logic needs to be mutex'ed or locked.

Comment: how much frequently the timeframes are being changed?

Comment: Pretty often. What matters is that given 10 WDs pro Project the request to recalculate the total price does not take longer than a couple of seconds.